# Choosing correct zoom level to display given area in square km using Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, area, zoom

I would like to set the zoom on a Leaflet map based on an area (in km^2).

I am looking for a simple function that would approximately convert an area of
510,064,472 km to zoom level 0 and (if I read the table of zoom level at https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Zoom_levels correctly) an area of 12,321 to zoom level of about 8.5 and so on.

Comment: Shall this function take the aspect ratio of the map container into account as well? The same area in a square map and a rectangular map might need different scales/zoom levels.

Comment: If it could take into account the map shape that would be great but I wasn't originally imagining something that sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

An approximation of a solution that works up to about zoom level 10:

`Math.round(Math.abs(Math.pow(area,1/8.5) - 12))`

(Since OSM uses a mercator projection the surface area of the OSM world seems to be closer to 1,500,000,000 KM^2 then 510,064,472)

I don't consider this a good solution and I am still hoping to find a better one.

Comment: May I remind you that EPSG:3857 (the CRS commonly used to display OSM) is based off a spherical mercator projection, and *not* on a conical projection.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error @IvanSanchez. I'm not sure where I got the idea that it was a conical projection but it certainly isn't.